# Почему toolbar отображается некоректно?

Tags: android

Почему toolbar уходит в контекстное меню? Как исправить?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/status_bar_orange"/>
```

Вот так отображается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так должно отображаться, на некоторых устройствах вполне корректно отображается тулбар
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот начало одного лаяута, где импортируется тулбар

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@color/layout_background">
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Comment: Остальная разметка где и как должно отображаться? Скорее всего, вам нужно разметить элементы в контейнере, например вертикальном `LinearLayout`

Comment: @pavlofff добавил в конце пример использования

Comment: контекстным меню вы называете статусбар и вам не нравиться, что тулбар заходит за статусбар? Такое происходит, когда в теме используется прозрачный статусбар.